Issues with Azure web app to reach Azure SQL managed instance
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, and it needs to reach an Azure SQL managed instance that exists in other resource group.
I already peered the virtual network of the managed instance with my web app virtual network.
I already created the inbound and outbound security rules on my network security group
inbound rule
outbound rule
On my web app I am using the default dns feature.
There is no firewall configured in the managed instance virtual network. The same in the web app virtual network.
When I debug the web app using visual studio I catch a timeout exception after the managed instance was not found.
If I run my web app from Visual Studio, I can reach the managed instance without problem.
I want to connect my Azure web app to my Azure SQL managed instance.

Try running a shell in SCM for your app and testing domain name resolution and connectivity from there. For windows app service plans run nslookup <yourManagedInstamceDomainName>. This should produce the instance private IP. And PowerShell Test-NetConnection -TcpPort 1433 -Host <privateIP>. For Linux, dig <sqlDomainName> and nc <privateIP> 1433.

@JCano try using these app settings for web app over vnet .check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#networking

Thank you @ArchitectJamie I tried but I was not able to reach the managed instance. Thank you anyway for the suggestion

@VivekVaibhavShandilya I added the environment variables that the article suggested and I tried to use the public connection string and It worked!

After adding the environment variable WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL to my webapp as the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#networking. I was able to reached my managed instance
